# How do I uninstall a package from terminal?

Tags: command-line, package-management, uninstall

Days ago, I installed Wine 6.0.2 (to run windows software) and Winetricks '20210206-next' to be able to easily use Wine.
However, I uninstalled wine recently using `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove winehq-stable`  . I got this command from internet.

Now when I type `wine` in terminal I get `bash: /usr/bin/wine: No such file or directory` as it should be.
However, when I type `apt list -a wine` I get  `wine/focal,focal 5.0-3ubuntu1 all`. Does it mean I still have Wine installed?
Also, I wanted to uninstall Winetricks. I used `sudo apt-get purge winetricks` then it says `Package 'winetricks' is not installed, so not removed`.

Please let me know how do I uninstall Winetricks. Btw when I type `apt list -a winetricks`  I get `winetricks/focal,focal 0.0+20200412-1 all`. Also, I can't see winetricks in my Ubuntu GUI package manager.

I ran `apt list --installed| grep wine*`, I can't see any package named Wine or Winetricks. However, when I run `winetricks` or `winetricks --version` I can see the package is there.

Well, I am using Ubuntu 20.04.
Here is the output to `dpkg -l | grep -i wine`

```
rc  wine-stable                                6.0.2~focal-1                         amd64        WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs
rc  wine-stable-amd64                          6.0.2~focal-1                         amd64        WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs
rc  wine-stable-i386:i386                      6.0.2~focal-1                         i386         WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs
```

Comment: You need to use `apt list --installed` to check installed packages. The command you are using list every package available in the repositpries. Also, [edit] you question and add the version of ubuntu you use.

Comment: You can simply use `apt remove` to remove any installed package, what is hard in that?

Comment: i've edited the question.

Comment: To be sure please add output of `dpkg -l | grep -i wine` to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apt list -a wine` or `apt list --all-versions wine` lists all available versions of wine. I do not have wine installed, and the results of `apt list -a wine` in my terminal are the same as yours:

```
Listing... Done
wine/focal,focal 5.0-3ubuntu1 all
```

Run `apt policy package` to check if a package is installed. The results of `apt policy wine` confirm that the wine package is not installed:

```
wine:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0-3ubuntu1
```

Partial results of `man apt` showing the results for the `list` option of `apt`:

```
list
    list is somewhat similar to dpkg-query --list in that it can
    display a list of packages satisfying certain criteria. It supports
    glob(7) patterns for matching package names as well as options to
    list installed (--installed), upgradeable (--upgradeable) or all
    available (--all-versions) versions.
```

The results of `apt list --installed wine` or `apt list -i wine` don't return any packages at all confirming that the wine package is not installed:

```
Listing... Done
```

When you run `winetricks` or `winetricks --version` you can see the package is there, because you did not install winetricks from the default Ubuntu 20.04 repositories. iinm you manually installed winetricks version 20210206-next with the following commands and did not manually remove winetricks from the `/usr/local/bin` directory where it is installed:

```
wget  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
chmod +x winetricks 
sudo mv -v winetricks /usr/local/bin
```

After manually removing winetricks from `/usr/local/bin` with `cd /usr/local/bin && sudo rm winetricks` run `apt policy winetricks` to check if it is still installed.

Comment: This worked. I don't remember exactly how I installed Winetricks. Isn't there any Windows equivalent to add or remove programs. Ubuntu Software Center does not shows all installed packages. Also, in my case, I used wget, and I can't see the package in  ' apt list --installed' .

Comment: There are multiple ways that winetricks could end up installed in `/usr/local/bin` . If you moved winetricks into `/usr/local/bin` with `sudo mv -v winetricks /usr/local/bin` then you can remove it using the built-in Files file browser application by installing the nautilus-admin package with `sudo apt install nautilus-admin` nautilus-admin is an extension for Nautilus to do administrative operations. It's not exactly like Windows Add/Remove Programs, but at least it has a GUI.

Comment: Packages that are compiled from source can be uninstalled similarly to Add/Remove Programs in Windows using the Software app if you converted the package  into a .deb package before you installed it using the checkinstall package (`sudo apt install checkinstall`) .